# Clockpicker setting default time to now in textbox and knowing AM or PM

Tags: jquery, clockpicker

I am using the clockpicker from http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/ and I am trying to figure out how to show the time in the value of the textbox. I have been able to set the 'now' time as default on the clock but I am having two problems.

**First problem**
The clock is not showing if its AM or PM from just using 'Now'

**Second problem** I am unable to display that time in the value of the textbox unless its selected from the clock. I want the time to already be displayed for now. But to allow the user the option to change it with the clock.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/YkvK9/1714/

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>test</label>
        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    $('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
                'default': 'now',
                twelvehour: true,
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this fix, which addresses many issues with the twelve hour functionality of the clock: https://github.com/diracleo/bootstrap-clockpicker